# golang exec.Command read std input

Tags: go

I have a go program that should invoke a ruby script.

I have a `runCommand` function:

```
func runCommand(cmdName string, arg ...string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, arg...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to start Ruby. %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I invoke it like this:

```
runCommand("ruby", "-e", "require 'foo'")
```

It works for most cases, except if there is a `gets` or any similar operation in the child process that needs to pause for an input.

I have tried setting `cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin`, but it does not wait for input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When there is `gets` in Ruby, can you enter input from your console? Does Ruby wait for that? Do you hit Enter after entering your input?

Comment: `gets` is in middle of a flow, and if I run the ruby script it waits for an input. Yes, I hit enter after the input. My real usecase is to invoke `pry` on the ruby side, and my expectation is `cmd.Run()` would wait for the `pry` REPL to complete.

Comment: If I run [this simple Go app](http://play.golang.org/p/0eWjtN2RWG) from your code, it works perfectly, waits for the input and properly prints the outpout. I'd say it is something in your Ruby code.

Comment: BTW, not at all related to your question but, you almost never need or want to directly call an errors' `Error` method. And if you're going to exit, you can send output to stderr and exit via the `log` packge. I.e. just `log.Fatal("Failed to start Ruby:", err)` will do.

Comment: Thanks for you comments everyone, I figured out that I was doing something stupid. @icza's point led me to troubleshoot it successfully. It turns out that my setup had multiple level of redirection and I missed redirecting `Stdin` at the first level.

Comment: @DaveC - thanks for the tip, am going to refactor this bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following program seems do what you ask for (my `runCommand` is almost identical to yours. I just changed the `=` to `:=` for the `err` line.) Are you doing something differently?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    runCommand("ruby", "-e", `puts "Running"; $in = gets; puts "You said #{$in}"`)
}

func runCommand(cmdName string, arg ...string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, arg...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to start Ruby. %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I finally figured out that this was valid code, and problem was elsewhere (I had multiple level of redirection, and I missed one of it).

Answer (score 7):

You might need to use a [pseudoterminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal). You can do this in go with this library: [github.com/kr/pty](http://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pty):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/kr/pty"
)

func runCommand(cmdName string, arg ...string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, arg...)
    tty, err := pty.Start(cmd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer tty.Close()

    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(tty)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            log.Println("[" + cmdName + "] " + scanner.Text())
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        io.Copy(tty, os.Stdin)
    }()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)
    runCommand("ruby", "-e", `
puts "Enter some text"
text = gets
puts text
  `)
}
```

Comment: Did not know about this library, +1 for introducing me to a pseudoterminal in golang. The problem was elsewhere, as I mentioned in my comment above. Thanks.