# GPG command works in shell but not in Go exec.Command()

Tags: go, gnupg

I am using gnupg to encrypt files with the following command:

```
gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r person@email.com name_of_file
```

This command works fine in shell. But it fails in go program with following error :

```
gpg: cannot open '/dev/tty': Device not configured
```

Here is the Code:

```
    func main() {
        var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer

        cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", `gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r person@email.com file_name.csv`)

        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr

        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        out := stdout.String() + stderr.String()
        fmt.Println(out)
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you run this in a Docker container? Also why do you call `/bin/sh`?

Comment: That has nothing todo with go. gpg thinks, there is a controlling tty and tries to access it, but as you started it without a controlling terminal, there is none.  See for example `man 4 tty`.

Comment: see the answer to this question that mentions psuedo terminals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207035/golang-exec-command-read-std-input